# Python fill up blank space from web extraction text with NaN

Tags: python-3.x, string, numpy

I have extracted some text from web and saved using numpy in format string (fmt="%s").
The data is successfully transferred and readable as follows:

```
250.0 1000 39.9 45.9 53  60 210 16
250.0 1000 39.9 45.9 53  60 210 16
250.0 1020 40.7          70 200 10
250.0 1010 40.1          95 175  9
250.0 1010 39.9 43.7 67 150 120 16
250.0 1000 39.5 49.5 34  80 190 15
```

The data consists 2 blank spaces at row 3 and 4 which I believe missing values originates from web. I tried to read the file (sample-250.dat) using numpy and loadtxt procedure :

```
data5 = np.loadtxt(path1+"sample-250.dat",dtype=object)
PRES=data5[:,0]
HIGHT=data5[:,1]
TEMP=data5[:,2]
DWPT=data5[:,3]
RELH=data5[:,4]
DRCT=data5[:,5]
md=data5[:,6]
SKNT=data5[:,7]
```

Sadly, the output shows error as follows : ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 3.
Anyone got ideas on how to read such data probably to replace those blank spaces with NaN values?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using pandas instead of numpy?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data5 = pd.read_table(path1+"sample-250.dat", header = None).values
```

data5 is what you need.

Comment: yes, I can read now and it reads in single rows but the blank still remains. any idea how to reshape  the element in new shape (6,8).